# where do I type this for node.js packaging into a .exe file (windows)

Tags: package, exe, node-webkit

I know this may seem like a duplicate, but hear me out. I have gone through many tutorials on how to do it, but they never quite answer my question. I want to know where you type:

```
copy /b nw.exe+app.nw app.exe
```

To make the two files the one .exe file. Thank you for any assistance.
What I mean by "where you type:

```
copy /b nw.exe+app.nw app.exe
```

is what software. Do you use the CMD, or is there something else?

Comment: Yes that looks like dos, so search for CMD in windows, and it'll bring up a black command line window and just type that in. I would be very suprised if the output file (app.exe) was actually a valid functioning exe though. Perhaps you could reference where you came across this command?

Comment: I guess you don't mean to include the | symbols? Use the backtick if you want to highlight code, i.e. `my code` is surrounded by *`* characters

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I didn't mean with the | symbols, no. I had just made my account when I made this question. I'll just edit that now.

Comment: So reading here.... https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/how-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps, the resultant `app.exe` will not be a valid exe, but when combined with appropriate files and zipped, it will be in a format suitable for installation by a special installer.